# jenkins configSubmit throwing ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error

Tags: http, jenkins, networking

When trying to change a job config and save in Jenkins, The browser is popping up `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error message.

I tried multiple browsers but no luck. Also I thought this could be issue with network and tried with my work network but failed there too.

Can someone help to resolve this issue?

Comment: We have the exact same issue. Did you ever get the bottom of this one? My suspicion is it's related to a max request length somewhere as we're seeing it when trying to save a DSL script. The empty response only occurs when the script is above a certainly length.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not getting to your Jenkins server probably.

Where do you have your `jenkins` server ? What port is it running ? What protocol (`http`/`https`) ? What is your network topology ? Is this a server on-prem, on-cloud, behind a LoadBalancer, started in a VM/docker ?

You're question has nothing to do so far with Jenkins or with Browsers, but with your Network ([more](https://blog.pcrisk.com/windows/12807-err-empty-response))

---

**UPDATE:** Based on the comments bellow, you may have a compatibility issue in Jenkins. Basically you have to upgrade or uninstall the culprit plugin. I would do a full backup and:

1. Check the Jenkins server log for errors.
2. Upgrade all plugins
3. Upgrade Jenkins
4. Guess the culprit plugin based on the config used in the Job
5. Uninstall one by one until the issue plugin is found
6. Report the [issue](https://www.jenkins.io/participate/report-issue/) - most probably for the plugin.

Comment: My jenkins is a on prem physical server, residing on port 8080 and it is running on http. I am trying to hit the server directly(no Load balancer).

Comment: to add more, i have both freestyle and pipeline jobs in my jenkins and the problem is only when saving freestyle job configuration.

Comment: Do you have any virtual host setup? What URL is setup in Jenkins for the server? how do you access it? I expect something like: http://jenkins.example.org:8080/. If you're able to access it, and you see the problem only when you save the config, it means the redirect setup after you save, takes you to a different URL. Find out the 2 URLs and compare them. Paste them here to be able to provide you more hints.

Comment: My jenkins URL is  http://hostname:8080 and yes i am able to acess it. The URL of the job cofigure page which i am able to acess is http://hostname:8080/job/app-auto-merge-branches/configure and the URL after saving the new config is http://hostname:8080/job/app-auto-merge-branches/configSubmit (This URl is returning ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Comment: @sandeepmalladi - I have updated my answer based on your comments. I also recommend you to update your question, as now it becomes very relevant. I recommend you provide details, like the errors in the log, the URLs that you specified in comment etc. Once you provide more details I would also consider to upvote your question.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Jenkins 2.277.3 and Jenkins 2.289.1. Upgrading to 2.289.2 resolved this issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , upgrading to 2.289.2 resolved the issue.
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66067